# Popup window not showing div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this JQuery code:

```
function JQueryPopup(value) {
    $(value).toggle();

    $('#JQueryClose').click(function(){
        $(value).hide();
    });

    $( document ).on( 'click', function ( e ) {
        $(value).hide();
    });

    $( document ).on( 'keydown', function ( e ) {
        if ( e.keyCode === 27 ) { // ESC
            $(value).hide();
        }
    });
}
```

and a HTML button that calls this function, it doesn't seem to be showing the popup window/div.

here is a fiddle with my full code: http://jsfiddle.net/XHLY8/3/

P.S. i do have this code on another page, i call the function like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">JQueryPopup('#customer_popup_notes');</script>
```

which works fine.

Comment: First clear all Console error by solving it

Comment: call your function like this
JQueryPopup($("#customer_popup_notes"));

Comment: Toggling is not working in your code

Comment: Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/XHLY8/6/

Comment: What is  problem with this fiddle ? http://jsfiddle.net/XHLY8/7/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the following:

```
$('#inbox_button').on('click', function(event){
  event.preventDefault(); // This isn't critical, but you would need 
  event.stopPropagation();
  JQueryPopup('#inbox_div');
});
```

You want to stop the click event from bubbling up and triggering the following:

```
$( document ).on( 'click', function { ... });
```

Otherwise your `#inbox_div` will be hidden before you can see it.

Here is a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y8CYC/).

I suggest reading up on [stopPropagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) and [preventDefault](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/).

Answer (score 0):

You dont need

```
$( document ).on( 'click', function ( e ) {
        $(value).hide();
    });
```

Which always hides the Bottom div no matter where u click .

Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XHLY8/7/)